# Wordpress Title without a loop in file like single.php

Tags: wordpress

Hi i'm trying to understand if the use of template tag like the_title() is good behaviour outside a loop.

I know that this type of question is very basic but i can't found THE answer.

single.php - the_title inside the loop:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>            
               <?php the_title(); ?>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

single.php - the_title outside the loop:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

I downloaded from underscores.me a basic theme and if i investigate the files i can see that most of them have a loop (also file like page.php or single.php include with get_template_part other files containing a loop).

When i follow some tutorial i can see the author use the_title() outside a loop and it works, but if i read the documentation i see that it's better use it inside (i'm not talking about use echo get_the_title() like an alternative).

I found you can also use single_post_title() outside the loop, the documentation said to use it with single post, i found it works on page.php, single.php, home.php, etc.:

```
<?php single_post_title() ?>
```

Can someone give me the correct answer?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Add the relevant code for example.

Comment: Hi, i hope this time my question is more detailed and understandable, thank you Jeroen.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, using `the_title()` outside the `while()` loop would still work on pages.

The way I look at this is, the whole page contains a loop for that specific page you are visiting. Calling the_title() would simply output the current page's title.

To further use `the_title()` within a loop, you can then create another loop inside said page to loop through more posts by setting a new loop.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I understand that using `the_title()` print it also outside the loop and that WordPress give us some data depending on the type of page we are visiting. What i can't understand if using some template tag outside the loop is a good way to code or not and if using a loop is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`echo get_the_title($post_id);`